# Remove all members from a group in WSO2 IS using SCIM endpoints

Tags: rest, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have created one group in WSO2 IS by using SCIM endpoint. Then i updated the group with some members. Now i want to remove all the members from the group, I have used the same update command to do this, But i couldn't remove all the members from the group. No errors are there.
I have used the following curl commands to do this.

Create Group :

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"displayName": "groupname"}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://example.com:9443/wso2/scim/Groups
```

Update group to add one member :

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PUT -d "{"displayName": 'groupname' ,"members":[{"value":"dfd437b5-2e52-4077-9c31-84bc2ea8c117","display":"hasinitg"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://example.com:9443/wso2/scim/Groups/328b8e27-4869-45c5-9857-1afa9aaacf59
```

Update group to remove the existing member :

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PUT -d "{"displayName": 'groupname' }" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://example.com:9443/wso2/scim/Groups/328b8e27-4869-45c5-9857-1afa9aaacf59
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation it doest support to remove all members. To get this done what you will have to do is. Delete the existing group and create it with the same name.